# ARP table on sg500x-48 not showing everything

Tags: networking, ssh, switch, arp

I have a sg500x-48 Cisco switch with 15 different machines/IP addresses connected to it. Nevertheless, ARP table shows only one entry, regardless of if I run 'show arp' through ssh or use WebGUI.

Should I run 'clear arp-cache' to clear the whole table, is it going to load all entries afterwards? Or, is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Do you have it setup for layer 2 or layer 3?

Comment: it is setup for layer 2

Comment: I Believe when you are setup for layer 2 you will only see one entry in the ARP table. And you will be able to only see mac addresses for the rest of the IPs. I believe Layer 3 you would be able to see all in the ARP table someone may correct me if im wrong on that.